# Convert Speech to text in iphone

Tags: iphone

I want to convert speech to text in iphone.
Is there any way. I had used vocalkit but it is not giving the true output.

**Edit:**

And i had also tried to use Openears for speech to text:- 
[OpenEars](http://www.politepix.com/openears/)
But then also it is not working properly.....

The problem with open ears is

i had tried to implement open ears through http://www.politepix.com/openears/yourapp .But i cant't able to understand how to use the openears in our app(Step -4).I had successfully configured it.If u have any demo our detail link with sample code then please send it.

Example:-

I had found the code from github:-
[Code Link](https://github.com/KingOfBrian%5d)

Not i this application when i speak anything it does not recognize properly.

I had edited my question.
Please check it
And i had also tried to use Openears for speech to text:- 
[OpenEars](http://www.politepix.com/openears/)
But then also it is not working properly.....

The problem with open ears is

i had tried to implement open ears through http://www.politepix.com/openears/yourapp .But i cant't able to understand how to use the openears in our app(Step -4).I had successfully configured it.If u have any demo our detail link with sample code then please send it.

What i want to do is:-

Whatever i speak it recognize the proper words with any language and want to do the particular action on the recognized text of the speech..
Please help me.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 7):

What is wrong with OpenEars, I have used it and its working perfectly fine in my project

Also there is another library available out there, here is the link.

http://www.ispeech.org/developers/iphone

Comment: @robin.Thanks for the reply.I had edited my question please check it.And help it If u have any solution like demo code or link.

Comment: How to get the output of speech. I implemented all the delegate methods but dont know where to go from here